# When data is passed to Mongo Schema, Array elements get lost

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a quiz application using mongo and express.

and here is how my schema looks like,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const quizSchema = new Schema({
  course: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  options: [
    { type: String, required: true },
    { type: String, required: true },
    { type: String },
    { type: String },
    { type: String },
  ],
module.exports = Quiz = mongoose.model("Fifth_question", quizSchema)
```

for instance I have an object as below

```
{
  course: 'fruit',
  title: 'Laravel: Blade',
  option: [ 'orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'mango' ],
  answer: 'orange'
}
```

and when I pass this object to schema liek below

```
const quiz = new quiz(obj)
```

it looses array element, it returns empty array

these are what I found online but still it does not work.
the same result.

```
options: {
  type: Array,
  default: []
}

or

options: [
  { option1: { type: String, required: true } },
  { option2: { type: String, required: true } },
  { option3: String },
  { option4: String },
  { option5: String },
],
```

can someone tell me what I am missing ?

and also the last one, array of object, in case we want to make not array of string and array of object, how am i supposed to fix my code?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Could just be a typo. Your schema defines `options` (plural) but your object has `option` (singular)